# Type issues for $$ in Bison

Tags: c++, parsing, bison

I am having some type issues that I cant seem to get past in bison

I have a grammar rule named `program` and I am trying to use `$$ = new Node("Program");`

I have the type defined as `%type <Node> program`, the Node class is defined in a separate header file which is included in the definition section.

I get an error `error: 'union YYSTYPE' has no member named 'Node'`, How do I go about getting the types right for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header has to be included in the lexer before the .tab.h

Answer (score 2):

In the bison file make sure you include `Node` in the %union and use lowercase `node` to prevent conflicts. Also you should be explicit with the header include code in bison by using [`%code requires`](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/html_node/Prologue-Alternatives.html)

bison example (I added a namespace for this example)

```
%code requires
{
#include "node.h"
}

%union {
    ns::Node *node; //notice lowercase node for the type
}

%type <node> program;

 /* If using a high enough version of bison implement a destructor */
%destructor { delete $$; } <node>

%%

program:        /* empty */  { $$ = new ns::Node("Program"); };

...
```

Comment: @fotg sorry had this typed up yesterday but never submitted, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `%type` definition, the generated parser assumes that the YYSTYPE (the type that holds the parsed intermediate values, such as `$$` or `$1`) is a union with a field with the same name than the type. So it expects that the YYSTYPE union has a field named `Node`.

First, since it looks like `Node` is already a class name, you should use a different identifier for your bison type:

```
%type <node> program
```

Then, you have two options:

a) Use `%union` to specify the definition of YYSTYPE:

```
%union {
    Node *node;
    //other types
}
```

b) Define the macro YYSTYPE to the real type of YYSTYPE, usually, but not necessarily an union:

```
union yystype {
    Node *node;
    //other types
}
#define YYSTYPE yystype
```

I personally prefer option a).

Comment: After trying these, I start getting compile time errors stating that Node doesn't have a type

Comment: That's probably because the generated .c file is not including the `Node` definition. Try `%{ #include "node.h" %}` or the `%code` stuff that Joe wrote.